# CakePHP 3.3 - Formbuilder first value to be 1

Tags: php, cakephp

I got a problem with CakePHP formbuilder. The first value of the options have to be 1 instead of 0.

View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="competentie">Competenties</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('competence._ids',['class'=>'form-control ','options'=> $competence,'div'=>false,'label'=>false]); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
    $category = $this->Cv->Category->find('list', ['keyField' => 'category_id', 'valueField' => 'category']);
    $this->set(compact('cv', 'category'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['cv']);
```

Any idea how i can make it start at value 1? Instead of 0.

Screenshot of it: https://i.gyazo.com/5ebeeeccc11ee08762efd9a84ba357ba.png

Comment: In your view check debug($competence) and see how data are comming..

Comment: Oh, competence in the view should be category, mb. But i get this in debug($category);

https://gyazo.com/8783f5b25ea99a2bca00cd8442e8b1db

Comment: where did you do that debug ? that would have return some array of value ?

Comment: did it in the edit view.. problem is its show everything right. But the option value start at 0 instead of 1.. I think its because of ['keyField' => 'category_id', 'valueField' => 'category']. But when i remove this, it shows the id in the option instead of the value.

Comment: if that answer doesn't fix that please post your categories table image with values..

Comment: If that answer works, you can accept that by clicking correct icon of left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does categories table have category_id field ? 
If not you may trying to do:

```
 $category = $this->Cv->Category->find('list', 
 ['keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'category']);
```

Otherwise look at the debug value one more time and confirm if data are coming correctly.

Comment: that is what i can just guess !

Comment: If that answer works, you can accept that by clicking correct icon of left side of the answer